# Destroy method has stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: page and authors, when i choose the destroy method it just returns the show page. The models are linked by telling the model that the author has_many :pages and the page belongs to many :author.

this is the code for my page controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def index
@pages = Page.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')
end

def show
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@page = Page.new
end

def edit
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
end

def create
@page = Page.new(params[:page])

if @page.save
      redirect_to(@page, :notice => 'Page was successfully created.')
  else
      render :action => "new"
  end
end

def update
@page = Page.find(params[:id])

  if @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
    redirect_to(@page, :notice => 'Page was successfully updated.')
  else
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end

def destroy
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
@page.destroy
end

def author
@pages = @author.pages
end

end
```

Where should I be looking to solve this problem, when i hit destroy it semds me to the page to destroy but nothing more, no :notice appears it just seems to not have the destroy method.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by

> choose the destroy method

But I'm assuming you're just accessing the `pages/:id` url in your browser?  This is the `show` action as you said.

In order to actually destroy your model (ie. access the `destroy` action in the controller) you need to send a `DELETE` to `/pages/:id`.

This is usually accomplished using something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @page, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Note the `:method => :delete`.  This will actually send a `DELETE` to the controller (assuming you've got your rails.js included to take care of this) and thus map to the `destroy` action instead of the `show` action

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look at:

- It's not clear what type of HTTP request you are sending to your application. The fact that the show action seems to be triggered makes me think that your request is an HTTP GET method. If you want the destroy action to be invoked, make sure it is an HTTP DELETE method.
- Have you checked your database to see if the ActiveRecord had been destroyed? It could be that you are not seeing any notice simply because you are not setting a flash notice message. For example:

---

```
def destroy
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  flash[:notice] = "Page successfully removed" 
  @page.destroy
  # You may also want to have a redirect here, e.g. redirect_to @pages
end
```

- On a separate note, not sure what you are trying to achieve with the author method in your controller but it doesn't look right. It's not restful and it seems to return an array of pages rather than an author.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled JavaScript in your browser? :)